# how to use services function in filters (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a filter that returns values based on the ID. These values are dynamically fetched and stored in an array using SERVICES. Now I want to use this SERVICE function to fetch values dynamically and that will be used in the filter.

How can I call a service function in the filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.filter('MyCustomFilter', ['ServiceHelper', function(ServiceHelper){
  return function(id) {
    ServiceHelper.get(id);
  }
}])
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, I have tried the above one but i am getting error like : angular.js:12450 TypeError: defaultServices._getList(...).then is not a function.

Comment: Are you using $http inside your _getList() ?  If you didn't use promise, you don't have access to the then().

Comment: I am not using promise in that function.

Comment: Hey Amin, thanks for the answer, now that worked perfectly after removing .then().